# I am stumped on how to replace quiz blank space with answer in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, str-replace

My code is below. I may have stared at the screen too long.  New to python and I'm unsure how to make the quiz when answered display the question and replace the blank_box with the answer in python 2.7 I am so frustrated I can't see straight. When I run the code the correct answer is acknowledged and the quiz advances but it reprints the questions with the blank_box holder instead of the correct answer in place of the place holder (blank_box).

```
if type(max_try) != int:
    print 'You selected an invalid number of attempts'
return get_max_try()    
if max_try < 1:
    print 'You selected an invalid number of attempts'
return get_max_try()
else:
    return max_try
def check (blank_number, lib, answer, answers, max_try):
blank_box = '__' + str(blank_number) + '__')
guess = raw_input('Please enter the answer for __'+str(blank_number) + '__: ')

if guess == answer:
    lib = lib.replace(blank_box, answer)
    print lib + '\n'
```

Comment: There's not enough code here for us to answer your question.  Please post a complete working example.  Lots of things, including the key quantity 'lib', aren't defined here at all.   Also, with your indentation all messed up, it makes it impossible to know what the proper flow through this code is.  This code won't compile due to the indentation alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve pointed out, this program is not a working program, but I do know how you could possibly remove text that has already been written:

```py
import sys

sys.stdout.write(“6543”)
sys.stdout.write(“\b\b65”)
```

The Output of this is `6565`.

This method uses `sys.stdout.write()`, which prints something without a new line, the part that makes it wok though, is `\b`, which is a backspace character, so when you type something else, it removes the last character you printed.